# Angular, asp.net.core webApi , Display server Error in angular <mat-error>

Tags: javascript, angular

How to display server-side error message in mat-error input validation, I can not bind it ...

```
updatePlayer(player: PlayerDto) {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/account/edit', player);
    }

this.updatePlayer(player).subscribe(p=>console.log(p));
```

This code just displays an array of errors and this description: "User name 'c1' is already taken."

in console, how to bind this errors.descriprion in mat-error of an input